# Why won't any unopened emails sync with my iPhone or Android from our Exchange 2003 server

Tags: exchange, iphone, activesync, android

My opened emails are syncing fine, but any unopened emails won't come through.  If I use Outlook Web Access to open the mail, then it syncs, of it I open it via Outlook it will sync also.  Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: Do they come through as soon as you've opened them? Sounds to me like it just syncs fairly slowly, so by the time you've opened it it hasn't synced yet, but soon after that it does actually download the messages?

Comment: No, it isn't a problem of timing.  I had 10 messages last night that remained unopened, and therefore not sync'd to either my android phone or iphone.  I opened the Outlook Web Access, opened one, then refreshed my phone, in came the message that was opened, but none of the other 9 that remained unopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be a problem with the anti-virus that was installed on the server.  It needed to be configured for "proactive scanning".  I found that if I manually scanned my mailbox then my iphone and android would receive the new, opened mail.  After setting the anti-virus package to proactively scan, I am getting my new mail to my phones.